# Associating a reservation with a flight in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a flight booking website using ASP.NET MVC. There are many flights and I want to add functionality that is basically making a reservation of a ticket for a certain flight.

I have the following models:

```
public class Flight
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string LocationFrom { get; set; }
    public string LocationTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public PlaneType PlaneType { get; set; }
    public string PlaneId { get; set; }
    public string PilotName { get; set; }
    public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }
    public int AvailableSeatsBusinessClass { get; set; }

    public virtual HashSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }

    public Flight()
    {
        Reservations = new HashSet<Reservation>();
    }
}

public class Reservation
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PersonalID { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public TicketType TicketType { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual HashSet<Flight> Flights { get; set; }

    public Reservation()
    {
        Flights = new HashSet<Flight>();
    }
}
```

Here is the create reservation method I am using in the reservations page:

```
// GET: Reservations/Create
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Reservations/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,FirstName,SecondName,LastName,PersonalID,PhoneNumber,Nationality,TicketType,Email")] Reservation reservation)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(reservation);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(reservation);
}
```

Since I have a separate reservation page, I want to link the reservation to a certain flight, so when I click on the details button on the flights page I can see all reservations for that given flight, but I have no idea how to do that.

Could you suggest any ideas? Btw I'm using SQL Server for a local database and Entity Framework in my project.

Comment: Which part of that are you struggling with? Storing the reservation in the database? Querying it back out of the database? Creating the markup for your details view? It's not clear to me which part of this you're actually needing help with.

Comment: I am struggling with associating the reservation to a certain flight. With the given code I create a Flight and I create a reservation but they are not linked with each other. Therefore, when I want to check the details for a certain flights there is no way for me to display all of the reservations for that flight since they are not linked.

Comment: Okay, so that association is called a relationship. There is [documentation on how to create EF Core Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table design should look this way. The EF will create the relation automatically.

```
public class Flight
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string LocationFrom { get; set; }
    public string LocationTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public PlaneType PlaneType { get; set; }
    public string PlaneId { get; set; }
    public string PilotName { get; set; }
    public int AvailableSeats { get; set; }
    public int AvailableSeatsBusinessClass { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Reservations> Reservations { get; set; }
}


 public class Reservation
   {
   {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PersonalID { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public TicketType TicketType { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int FlightId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string FlightNo {get; set;}
   
    public virtual Flight Flight { get; set; }
   
}
```

Note that the NotMapped data annotation is to show the flight no in your view without need to save the field in your database. The controller will show u how to display it.

For the Controller

I think u should create a ActionResult to search for the flight first. Then let user to select to flight and redirect to create action for reservation with the flight details.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int FlightId)
{
    var model = new Reservation();
    Reservation.FlightId = FlightId;
    Reservation.FlightNo = db.Flights.Find(FlightId).Code;
    return View(model);
}
```

Post method will be the same except that u need to add in FlightId.